# sql - Searching part of string in multiple columns

Tags: sql

The below query works for me.

```
Select *
From table1
Where 'string' In (col1, col2, col3)
```

I want to use wildcards and search for a string in any of the listed columns.
Tried the below with no success.

```
Select *
From table1
Where '%string%' In (col1, col2, col3)
```

or

```
Select *
From table1
Where In (col1, col2, col3) Like '%string%'
```

Both don't work.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Amos

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is `or`:

```
Select *
From table1
Where col1 like '%string%' or
      col2 like '%string%' or
      col3 like '%string%' ;
```

Many databases support regular expressions or full text indexes, which can simplify this.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.
 I was trying to search for a string value or part of that string in any of the columns. In other words, searching for a word or part of word in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Wild cards don't use `IN` they use `LIKE` -- so you have to do it this way:

```
Select *
From table1
Where '%string%' like col1
   or '%string%' like col2
   or '%string%' like col3
```